# How to get user's location in iOS using google plus sdk?

Tags: ios, ios7, location, google-plus

I am integrating Google Plus login in my app along with Facebook and Twitter login. So, is it possible to get user's location(city) Like Facebook and Twitter? If yes, how?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a field in the Google+ profile for "places lived" that may contain a location. However, it is not very common for people to share that publicly, so you will likely find only a small proportion of users have it available.

If you want to try, you can retrieve the profile data by following this documentation: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people#retrieve_profile_information - this returns `GTLPlusPerson` for the current user.

From that, look at the `placesLived` property: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Plus/Generated/GTLPlusPerson.h?r=246#128

Comment: How would you find which one is the current place from that array?

Comment: The "primary" property on the place in the array will be true: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Plus/Generated/GTLPlusPerson.h#342

Comment: Got it. I spent whole day going through different docs and forums but could not find any solution. Thanks a lot @Ian.